# Ionic side menu from top

Tags: angularjs, menu, ionic-framework

i'm starting on ionic, and in this project I need the menu to show from top, but behind the top bar.

Of course I looked into the [ionic doc's side menu](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/directive/ionSideMenus/).
Also saw [this](http://ionicframework.com/docs/nightly/api/service/$ionicPopover/) but I don't think it's the best solution.
Can you help me with that?

Comment: Can we have your code please.

Comment: @Braian. Did you find any solution?

Comment: I made it hard coded, but after all the client decided to go with side menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at below link just as you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/brayancastrop/fgcruwxg/1/

```
(function () {
angular.module('sampleApp', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  })
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {
  $ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0);
  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html"
  })

  .state('app.events', {
    url: "/events",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/events.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.event', {
    url: "/events/:id",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/event.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.conference', {
    abstract: true,
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/conference.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.conference.information', {
    url: "/events/:id/conferences/:conferenceId/information",
    views: {
      'conferenceInformation': {
        templateUrl: "templates/conference/information.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.conference.presentation', {
    url: "/events/:id/conferences/:conferenceId/presentation",
    views: {
      'conferencePresentation': {
        templateUrl: "templates/conference/presentation.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.conference.questions', {
    url: "/events/:id/conferences/:conferenceId/questions",
    views: {
      'conferenceQuestions': {
        templateUrl: "templates/conference/questions.html"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.conference.notes', {
    url: "/events/:id/conferences/:conferenceId/notes",
    views: {
      'conferenceNotes': {
        templateUrl: "templates/conference/notes.html"
      }
    }
  });


  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/events');
});
```

})();

Comment: Hello Steevan, thank you for the answer but as I said on the post, I need the menu from the top, not from the left. Can you do that?